# Delete duplicate words in a string that has concatenated other variables previously

Tags: vba, ms-access, duplicates

I have a form in MS Access that collects feedback from 4 users. After users have filled the form there's a variable called "sResultAll" that concatenates all feedback (from several textboxes) into it and passes its value to a Textbox called "txtRecommendation".

```
sResultAll = sResult1 & sResult2 & sResult3 & sResult4
txtRecommendation.Value = sResultAll
```

The problem I face is several users provide literally the same feedback so I need a way to eliminate duplicates within the variable sResultAll.

Thanks in advance for any contribution.

Comment: You could use a scripting dictionary to get rid of duplicates, and then create the result string from the dictionary keys.

Comment: Thanks so much @BraX! Your approach was dead on! I'm sorry I wasn't able to share a code, I'd never worked with the "Dictionary Object" before and didn't really know how to even start coding.

Answer (score 1):

Friday evening 5:55, got nothing else to do. Here's a freebie:

As @braX suggested, a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) is great at keeping track of unique strings because it can quickly search its current keys with the `.Exists` function. This lets you check if the string has already been entered, before adding it to the collection.

To improve this idea, I also suggest that you sanitize the strings before comparing them. Force them all to the same case and remove non-alphanumeric characters. This way, the strings will still match regardless of white-space, punctuation, or capitalization.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Const sResult1 As String = "George"
    Const sResult2 As String = "Fred"
    Const sResult3 As String = "John"
    Const sResult4 As String = "gEORGE  "

    Debug.Print Join(DistinctOf(sResult1, sResult2, sResult3, sResult4), ", ")
    'Outputs: George, Fred, John
End Sub
Function DistinctOf(ParamArray Strings() As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim AlphaNumericOnly As Object
    Set AlphaNumericOnly = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With AlphaNumericOnly
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]+"
    End With

    Dim Distinct_Strings As Object
    Set Distinct_Strings = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim str As Variant
    For Each str In Strings
        Dim AO_str As String
        AO_str = AlphaNumericOnly.Replace(LCase(str), "")
        If Not Distinct_Strings.exists(AO_str) Then Distinct_Strings.Add AO_str, str
    Next
    
    DistinctOf = Distinct_Strings.Items
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Toddleson!!! Your sample code opened my mind on to how to resolve my need!!